# How to increase counter value when no record is found in mysql database

Tags: mysql

Here is the concept:

I have created a website and I want to know the NO-HITS count day wise.

Let's say I have hosted a website on 2 Jan 2017 and it was opened by someone for the first time on 1 Feb 2017. 
So the count I want is the total number of days in particular month website was not clicked. Here the count should be 30 for the month of Jan.

Next website was clicked on 10 Feb and 20 Feb.

**So the final count I want is: (On date 22 Feb)**

Jan - 30

Feb - 19

**Table can be considered like:**

```
Website_information_table

id websiteLaunchedDate

1  2-Jan-2017

Website_history_1

id isWebSiteClicked epochTime

1 YES 1-Feb-2017

2 YES 10-Feb-2017 ....

Website_history_2

id isWebSiteClicked epochTime
```

**My current query is:**

```
select month1 as DATE, SUM(day_count) as counter from( SELECT epochTime AS month1, 
if(SUM(isWebsiteClicked='YES') > 0, 0, 1) AS day_count 
FROM myTable 
where 
id=1 
and 
epochTime between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-02-22 15:23:13' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(epochTime, '%Y%m%d')) as alias GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(month1, '%Y%m')
```

For the case1 (website_history_1) is considered where data will be there either YES or NO. Here I am getting the count.

For the case2 (website_history_2)
No data available in the table Website_history_2 there is nothing gets counted as the table is empty.

**NOTE: Website_information_table will not be empty in any case.**

**So finally what I need?**

1. The total number of days count (month wise) in case of no record.

Comment: So you mean if table is empty then count should be 0, right?

Comment: No. If the website_history tables are empty that means website is hosted but no one has visited yet. So I need the count for month1 is: 31 and month2 (feb): 21 (as today is 22 ) @nilesh

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for you. This will cope with up to 1000 days (easy enough to expand).

It works by getting the first day of the month of the start of the range and the last day of the month of the end of the range. If then returns the first date plus up to 1000 days while it is less than the last day.

This is LEFT OUTER JOINed against the real table based on matching the date. This will give you every date in the range and a count of how many hits on that date (which will include days where the number of hits is 0).

This is then used as a source for the outer SELECT, which gets the month and year, and uses SUM to count the number of rows for that month and year which have 0 hits.

```
SELECT MONTH(out_date), 
        YEAR(out_date),
        SUM(IF(site_used = 0, 1, 0))
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(sub1.each_day) AS out_date,
            COUNT(myTable.id) AS site_used
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL (units.a + 10 * tens.a + 100 * hundreds.a) DAY) AS each_day
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(MIN(epochTime)), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(MIN(epochTime)))-1 DAY) AS start_date, 
                    LAST_DAY(DATE(MAX(epochTime))) AS end_date
            FROM myTable
            WHERE epochTime between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-02-22 15:23:13'
        ) sub0
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) hundreds
        WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL (units.a + 10 * tens.a + 100 * hundreds.a) DAY) <= end_date
    ) sub1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable
    ON sub1.each_day = DATE(myTable.epochTime)
    GROUP BY DATE(sub1.each_day)
) sub2
GROUP BY MONTH(out_date), 
        YEAR(out_date)
```

You could easily expand this to cover a larger or smaller date range, and you could improve performance by splitting up the month and year earlier in the query